# strange behavior of a ternary in a variadic macro

Tags: gcc, macros

I had fun writing a "foreach" function similar to the one in javascript. Compiled with GCC (gcc re.c) It is relatively simple:

```c
#define _LAMBDA(return_type, function_body)\
    ({ return_type __fn__ function_body __fn__; })

#define _FOREACHNFA(item, arr, arr_length, func, ...) ({\
    char **(*action)(char *item, int __VA_ARGS__) = func;\
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_length; i++) action(arr[i], i);\
})

#define _FOREACHNF(item, arr, arr_length, func) ({\
    char **(*action)(char *item) = func;\
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_length; i++) action(arr[i]);\
})

/*
 * we need a comma at the start for ##_VA_ARGS__ to consume then
 * the arguments are pushed out in such a way that 'cnt' ends up with
 * the right count.  
 */
#define _N__ARG(...) _N__ARGS(,##__VA_ARGS__,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)
#define _N__ARGS(z,a,b,c,d,e,f,cnt,...) cnt

/**
 * Performs the specified action for each element in an array.
 * @param item Variable coontaining each cases.
 * @param arr Array to perform action.
 * @param body Action for each element.
 * @param index? Index in the array. 
 */
#define E(item, arr, body, ...) ({\
    ((_N__ARG(__VA_ARGS__)) ?\
    _FOREACHNFA(item, arr, 2, _LAMBDA(char **, (char *item, int __VA_ARGS__) body), __VA_ARGS__) :\
    _FOREACHNF(item, arr, 2, _LAMBDA(char **, (char *item) body)));\
    arr;\
})

/**
 * Returns array after performing.
 * @param e New Array
 */
static inline char **foreach(char **e)
{
    return (e);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *messages[] = {"test", "test2"};

    foreach(E(message, messages, {
        printf("%s\n", message);
    }));

    return 0;
}
```

In macro E, the number of Va_arg is "determined", and depending on it, a function that manages va_arg or not is called.
From here there is a problem. If we try:

```c
int main(void)
{
    char *messages[] = {"test", "test2"};

    foreach(E(message, messages, {
        printf("%s\n", message);
    }, i));

    return 0;
}
```

It works very well, the macro _FOREACHNFA is called, but if we print i, we have:

```sh
re.c: In function ‘__fn__’:
re.c:62:27: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         printf("%d %s\n", i, message);
                           ^
re.c:22:36: note: in definition of macro ‘_FOREACHNF’
     char **(*action)(char *item) = func;\
                                    ^~~~
re.c:44:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘_LAMBDA’
     _FOREACHNF(item, arr, 2, _LAMBDA(char **, (char *item) body)));\
                              ^~~~~~~
re.c:61:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘E’
     foreach(E(message, messages, {
             ^
re.c:62:27: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
         printf("%d %s\n", i, message);
                           ^
re.c:22:36: note: in definition of macro ‘_FOREACHNF’
     char **(*action)(char *item) = func;\
                                    ^~~~
re.c:44:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘_LAMBDA’
     _FOREACHNF(item, arr, 2, _LAMBDA(char **, (char *item) body)));\
                              ^~~~~~~
re.c:61:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘E’
     foreach(E(message, messages, {
             ^
```

It seems that the _FOREACHNF function is called despite the fact that the ternary does indeed call _FOREACHNFA
We have the opposite case if we do not put an index
I've tried to inverse the ternany but the result is exactly the same.

I hope you have an idea and you can help me ! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Macros don't care abut binaries or ternaries or types or any of this stuff. They turn (barely readable) text into (totally unreadable) text. If you are debugging macros, then the questions are, what is the input, what is the output of the preprocessor, and are you satisfied with it? If not, let's debug the macros themselves. If yes, let's ignore the macros and debug the preprocessed code.

Comment: This question reminded me why one should not never use similar macros.

Comment: BTW macros are not `called`

Comment: By the way this is choke full of undefined behaviour and unknown to mankind compiler extensions, so technically this is not C. If you want this code to compile with a specific compiler, you should at least tell what that compiler is, and what are the options you are using.